# How to gm convert with custom arguments to cut down the file size?

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I am trying to convert images to cut down the file size with `graphicsmagick` on `node`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm).

- images are downloaded from `icon.src` crawled across random websites's `manifest.json`
- input image formats varies. (`png`, `jpg`, `ico`, `svg`, `webp`, etc)
- input image sizes varies from `16x16` to `512x512`
- output size is the first priority, and it will be displayed at 120px

Here is what I would execute in command shell:

```
gm convert inputFilePath -colors 128 -size 64x64 -resize 64x64 +profile "*" 
-depth 5 -define png:compression-filter=2 -define png:compression-level=9 
-define png:compression-strategy=1 output.png
```

Here is what I tried in javascript:

```
 gm(inputPath)
   .resize(64, 64)
   .colors(128)
   .bitdepth(5)
   .noProfile()
   .write(outputPath, function (err) {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
     } else {
       doSomething();
     }
```

1. Am I approaching the right way?
2. How do I add multiple `-define png: stuff` into js?
3. Is it possible to compress even more than what I have tried above?
4. Should I display the image at 128px?

Comment: i think `-size 64x64` is superfluous as you don't subsequently create any canvases, gradients or patterns. I think `-depth 5` is superfluous and ignored. I think you should reduce the colours with `-colors 128` **after** your `-resize 64x64` because that potentially adds colours.

Comment: i think you can use `-quality 92` to steer PNG compression in a similar way to what you have and it is more simply translated into *"node-ish"*. Try it!

Comment: ugh.. actually the default value for `-quality` is 75, so increasing the value resulted increase of file size